# How to make flowlayoutpanel components responsive?

Tags: windows-forms-designer

I am trying to achieve a responsive design mechanism using Win Forms C#. The approach I adopted now is to create container flowlayoutpanel then several tablelayoutpanels to it with controllers as showing in the below Image:

[image]

The Image shows that the flowlayoutpanel flow direction is set to left to right and the table docked to the top. the table layout controls are anchored top, right left. The problem is when resizing the tablelayoutpanels are stacked vertically but an extra room is created. View Image Two.

[image]

I tried to remove the extra space room by anchoring tablelayoutpanels to top, left, right. But did not work. The proposed way is to calculate the offset and do the adjustment. But unable to calculate the offset. How Can I make tablelayoutpanels fills the extra spaces and extend the last tablelayoutpanels width in accordance to other tablelayoutpanels until the extra room fits the tablelayoutpanel from second row. Please Consider that I would like to continue using flowlayoutpanel.

Comment: Not sure what extra room you mean. If children don't fit into FlowLayoutPanel, they get wrapped into a new row.

Comment: In the second image right hand side when resizing the form an extra room gets created an empty space I would the table layout panel to fill that space and when there is enough space for integer table layout then all table layout will adjust its size

Comment: The FlowLayoutPanel doesn't automatically resize controls to fill the available space. It will only insert "line breaks". It would be impossible for it to know when to break if controls have a dynamic size. Are you sure you want that anyway? It would make for an extra jumpy UI.

Comment: Yes I would like kindly to know how possible to to achieve what I did explain. adjust the table layout to fill the remaining space. please in your answer can you ensure that the remaining space width is applied to the three table layout as showing in image 2. Further, table layout inside the flow layout should increase in size to fill the remaining space.  @Ray

Comment: You'll probably have to write a custom layouting logic. I can't think of anything that allows this with built-in containers.